# How to show that $\sup(A + B) = \sup\{x + y : x \in A, y \in B\} = \sup A + \sup B$ for bounded subsets $A, B$ of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Write
$A + B = \{x + y : x \in A, y \in B\}$.  Show that $\sup(A + B) = \sup A + \sup B$.

This is a problem from an assignment from my analysis course.
the two definitions I  know of supremum is that it is the least upper bound and also for all $\epsilon >0 \sup(S)-\epsilon < a$ for some $a$ belonging to the set $S$.

I am unable to prove this using the above definitions (though the second one is actually a theorem that can be proven from the previous definition).  I have already tried writing the definition of supremum and saying that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $a+b$ belonging to $A+B$ such that $\sup(A+B)<a+b$
But I am unable to proceed further.

Can anyone please provide a right approach to solve this problem and what lemmas must be proven.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Can you at least see why $\sup A+\sup B$ is an upper bound of $A+B$? Given that, can you see how to proceed?

Comment: I have edited the question to show how much I have actually tried. To be honest I am beginner to analysis and have not done a lot of progress on this question.

Comment: @Crosby Yep I see it's an UB.

Comment: @NKB Okay, now can you show it is the *least* upper bound? What do you know about $\sup A$ and $\sup B$, by definition.

Comment: How do I do that ? Is it by assuming that suppose a supremum less than sup(A) + sup(A) exists?

Comment: @NKB Use the fact that if $M$ is an upper bound of $A$ then $\sup A\le M$ and if $N$ is an upper bound of $B$ then $\sup B\le N$. What can we say about $M+N$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Supposing that a supremum less than $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ exists is a good idea for arriving at a contradiction.

Comment: @Crosby M+N  will always be greater than sup(A) + sup(B) .

Comment: @NKB Yes, and we are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote in the comments that you see why $supA+supB$ is an upper bound of the set $A+B$. Now you just have to prove it is the least upper bound. Alright, so fix $\epsilon>0$. Then you know there exists $a\in A$ such that $a>supA-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and there exists $b\in B$ such that $b>supB-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So then $a+b\in A+B$ and $a+b>supA-\frac{\epsilon}{2}+supB-\frac{\epsilon}{2}=supA+supB-\epsilon$. Hence anything smaller than $supA+supB$ is not an upper bound of $A+B$.